# Camel acknowledgement in test cases java

Tags: java, junit, apache-camel

I have a camel configuration in project as shown below:

```
from("jmsDestinationUri")
        .id("DataWriteRoute")
        .autoStartup(consumerActive)
        .process(exchange -> fileHandler.dumpMessageToDisk(exchange))
        .unmarshal(new JsonDataFormat(JsonLibrary.Jackson) {{ setUnmarshelType(MyBean.class)}})
        .process(feedProcessor)
        .log("records successfully written to DB.");
```

I am calling this from my test class as follows:

```
jmsTemplate.send("jmsDestinationUri", new MessageCreator() {

  @Override
  public javax.jms.Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
    BytesMessage bytesMessage = session.createBytesMessage();
    bytesMessage.writeBytes(message.getBytes());
    return bytesMessage;
  }
});
```

The class is converting JSON message, enriching it and persisting to DB.

Is there any way to collect acknowledgement if the process method in route is completed or not? I have to put assertions on data persisted to DB.

Comment: Are you try to test the database insert in the test? This is unusual for simple unit tests, however you might have different requirements. Anyway you can add a mock component to the end of your route then assert if the message has reached this component. If the insert fails it would not reach the mock component

Comment: Look at Camel testing where there are some details on how you can advice Camel routes (or use the NotifyBuilder) to test for such conditions. Also if you have a copy of the CiA2 book then read the testing chapter.

Comment: @ClausIbsen I got CiA 1st and CiA 2nd. They are good very good!